# Error loading package list:pypi.python.org in Pycharm 2017.2.4 with Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am getting the error: Error loading package list:pypi.python.org.. when I try to install new packages.

Please can anyone help me to solve the error.

Comment: Is this a problem you only have in PyCharm, say on the command line `pip install xyz` works?

Comment: Also, is there any more detail to the error message? What do you see when you open the `Manage Repositories` screen? Are you able to open [https://pypi.python.org](https://pypi.python.org) in your browser?

Comment: When I give as.. python3 pip install cv2..It says 

python3: can't open file 'pip' [Errno 2] No such file or directory

When I try to open in browser, it says,
This site cant be reached.

I can see only https://pypi.python.org/simple in the Mng Repositories

Comment: I am using Raspbian OS.

Comment: No more details to error message

Comment: The site says..The web page at https://pypi...might be temorarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: From what I can gather, this appears to be not a problem with PyCharm itself, but a network connectivity issue, as indicated by the fact that you cannot connect in a browser. You should be able to see this in a terminal too when issuing the command line `ping pypi.python.org`. Fixing the connectivity problem should resolve your issue.

Comment: But It shows connected with ip address..I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't set a useable repository-url for.
Just do it now:

File --> Settings --> Project XXX --> Project Interpreter --> Add(Plus icon on the right) -->
Manage Repositories-->Add(Plus icon on the right)

Now input one true repository-url and click "OK".

Or maybe you get work from a network by proxy?
Search "proxy" in the settings page, then select one to set.